Can I make a consistantly sized corner mask-composite for an image?
I have multiple images that I'd love to have the exact same size of an corner cut-out (like of you were to fold a corner of a page). I've tried using polygon(), but when an image isn't the same dimensions as the majority, the shape changes.
I've tried using an SVG as a mask-image, but I can't seem to get it to work properly with my project.
My client is using squarespace for the development, and I'm fairly new to the builder, and from what I can tell, it doesn't allow for :root css compatibility.
These are a couple examples of what I have tried:

The codepen listed here.


#block-be2f56f7b09c1e03d16d img {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 100%,80px 100%,0 calc(100% - 20px));
}


The advice listed here; however, I only see any kind of change when I adapt the code to read:

#block-be2f56f7b09c1e03d16d img {
mask: url('https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/666cc44ae1d4196d1b3ab997/77f9aca1-8e05-4b5b-bd7d-7181a4c46a9d/Corner+Mask.png?content-type=image%2Fpng'),
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0);
  mask-composite: exclude;
  mask-size: 25%;
  mask-position: bottom left;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}

With this method, it gives me the desired effect, however the only amount of the image seen is the width of the mask. See the snippet below:


.image {
   mask: url('https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/666cc44ae1d4196d1b3ab997/77f9aca1-8e05-4b5b-bd7d-7181a4c46a9d/Corner+Mask.png?content-type=image%2Fpng'), linear-gradient(#000 0 0);
  mask-position: bottom left;
  mask-size: 25%;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-composite: exclude;
}
<div id="column-1">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" class="image">
<h2>Some Text Here</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>




the clip-path your are using should give the same cut whataver the size

As @TemaniAfif has pointed out, that clip path will give the same size cut out whatever the dimensions of the img. Can  you create a runnable snippet which shows the problem?

You can take some images and use that clip path and see what happens. This should be straightforward to insert as a snippet. You can upload images via the editor or use different size ones from e.g. lorem picsum. Neither your codepen nor website are using the clip path which you show in your question and that is what will give you the same size cut out.

@A Haworth, I've added the snippet to the OP.

Is there a reason you aren't using the clip-path? That clip-path should give you a consistent sized 'bite' out of any size image. Why introduce mask?

Here is an example, using the snippet you give but with the clip-path not the mask.
The clip-path has fixed the size of the amount taken out by using px units so any image of any aspect-ratio/size will have the same amount taken out.


div>img {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 80px 100%, 0 calc(100% - 20px));
}
<div id="column-1">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" class="image">
  <h2>Some Text Here</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>



ADDED: snippet to show the same size bite is taken out regardless of image dimensions:


<style>
  div>img {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 80px 100%, 0 calc(100% - 20px));
  }
</style>
<div> <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" class="image"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/600" class="image"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/200" class="image"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/300/300" class="image">
  <img
    src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/600/200" class="image"></div>




I tried using this method, but the image bite isn't consistent. Which is why I attempted to use the mask. I figured that if I could have a solid triangle cutout, then it wouldn't matter what ratio the image is. If the image is portrait, the triangle is tall, and not equal length on the horizontal side.

The image bite is consistent, it is exactly the same for each image in every aspect-ratio. I will update my answer with a second snippet that shows this. Are you certain that what you are looking for is a 'bite' that is exactly the same size whatever the image size, or are you wanting something that alters with the aspect ratio and/or absolute size of the image?
